# Composés du verbe dire et du verbe faire

Tags: conjugaison

Les composés de dire ne se conjuguent pas tous de la même façon à la 2e personne du pluriel.

> Vous dites/redites.
>
> Vous contredisez/dédisez/interdisez/médisez/prédisez.
>
> Vous maudissez.

En revanche tous les composés de verbe (au moins ceux qui me sont connus) se conjuguent d'après le modèle **vous faites** (contrefaites, défaites, satisfaites, etc.).

Pourquoi ce comportement différent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that's actually a tough question, and I find an answer from this [french article](https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/dites-mais-medisez)

There is 3 kinds for these verbs :

1. *dire* and *redire* which conjugate *'vous -dites'*
2. *contredire,* *médire,* *prédire,* *dédire,* *interdire* which conjugate *'vous -disez*'
3. maudire which conjugate *'vous maudissez*'

The original conjugation for 2  was *-dites* (e.g. *vous contredites*). Around the XVII e century, both conjugation could be found. The *-disez* was probably prefered due to 2 factors :

- the little difference between the present (*vous dites)* and simple past (*vous dîtes*)
- by analogy to the other verbs in *-ire*, which for the most, are conjugate *'-isez'* (e.g. *vous lisez*)

*Dire* probably stay the same due to its important use. According to the author, it's more difficult to change a word when it's used a lot (that's why common verb like *être* and *avoir* got such special conjugation, even in other languages).

Finally, for the verb *maudire* (curse), the explanation is close to the second kind of verb. But instead to conjugate it as other verb in *-ire*, it's probably the antonym *bénir* (bless) which was choose (*vous bénissez*).

Hope that's explain your question !

Answer (score 1):

`dire` est un **verbe du troisième groupe**.

D'après [ceci](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frmodeledire.php) :

> Le verbe **dire** fait "vous dites" à la deuxième personne du pluriel du
>   présent de l'indicatif. **Il s'agit d'une exception** par rapport à cette
>   forme qui se termine généralement en -ez.
>
> Mais ceci **n'est pas valable pour les dérivés de dire** (**sauf redire**) :
>   contredire, dédire, interdire, médire, prédire. Dans ce cas, on dit
>   "vous contredisez", "vous médisez" de manière tout à fait régulière.
>
> On remarquera que l'**exception porte uniquement sur le présent de
>   l'indicatif**. Au subjonctif, on dit que vous disiez.
>
> **Redire se conjugue de la même manière que dire** : vous redites. C'est
>   le seul des dérivés de dire de cette forme.
>
> On notera également que **maudire est un verbe du troisième groupe** et **se
>   conjugue sur la base de finir** et fait son participe passé en maudit.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Je sais le site. Ma question concerne plutôt la (ou les) raison(s) pour ce comportement différent (en particulier du verbe dire).